Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client Nodejs-grafana
I made a node js express code that allow me to connect to a server ( reverse proxy ) from apache , so I made this script to when I go to the url it logged in automatically , but it display this error :

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ClientRequest.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:703:11)
at ProxyServer. (file:///Users/mohamedyassinemessaoud/Documents/Yassine/PFE/Backend/server.js:87:12)

my code is like that
Code Nodejs
import httpProxy from 'http-proxy';
let serverProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

const username = 'anthony';
const password = 'anthony';
const basicAuth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`).toString('base64');

serverProxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res) {
  // Set headers before sending the response
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Set Authorization header for Basic Auth if body is present
  if (!proxyReq.getHeader('Content-Length') && req.body) {
    const bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(bodyData));
    proxyReq.write(bodyData);
  }

  // Set Basic Auth header
  proxyReq.setHeader('Authorization', basicAuth);
});

app.all('/dashboard(/*)?', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Rewritten URL:", req.url);
  serverProxy.web(req, res, {
    target: 'http://localhost:80',
    prependPath: false
  });
});

how to fix it and thanks

[SOLVED]
move the proxyReq.setHeader('Authorization', basicAuth);
in the top of res
serverProxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res) {

//just put it here 
  proxyReq.setHeader('Authorization', basicAuth);

  // Set headers before sending the response
 
  // Set Authorization header for Basic Auth if body is present
  if (!proxyReq.getHeader('Content-Length') && req.body) {
    const bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(bodyData));
    proxyReq.write(bodyData);
  }

});

